# Storing/retrieving multiple form input submissions by same user to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a simple form that asks "how are you doing right now at this moment?" and they select #1-10 from a dropdown.

The challenge: the user will answer this question endlessly over time, and I'd like to, if possible, store their ongoing answers in 1 column of a record with their unique user_id. Since they can potentially have hundreds of submissions to the question, what would the best way to store and retrieve their stored answer? There will be an option for them to view their past 5, 10, or even 100 answers so they can see a pattern over time how they're doing. Their info would be displayed probably in a table going across the screen like:

Here's how you've been doing:
2  4  8  9  4  9  4 etc etc

Is there a way, and is it in this case recommended, to save all their submitted answers to the question in 1 single table row column? If so, can you give me an idea of the mysql code to save ... and code to retrieve it? I would create x # of columns to save each answer if there was a known total, but in this case, we don't know how many there will be.

I wasn't able to find a solution to online.

Comment: You are going to get so many different opinions that this question will probably get closed.  It does not help that you didnt at least provide some starting code.  However, I would remove that thought of a single row, column from your head.  Since, you want to store many entries for each user, I would create a table with columns (userId, datetime, mood).   The store as many rows as you need for each user and/or for all users

Comment: sorry for the delay ... didn't get notification of a response. Thank you Jeff. I am rather new to this so thank you for your insight. I have removed single row, column from thy head :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , according to the **Jeff**, If I were you, I will create some table that we call it temporary_answer with the field,

> user_id, question_id, answer_id, created_datetime

And you will able to fetch this temporary answer anytime, anywhere by filtering the user_id and created_datetime. I have done with this when I was developing e-learning sites. I hope this answer can help.

CMIIW.

Comment: thanks ... I'll follow the advice you and Jeff provided. With your experience of developing elearning sites, how are you at teaching/coaching? Might you be open/available to be hired for a couple hours walking through the overall project I'm working on? I've got some fundamental questions on best practices. We'd use screen sharing to connect. Thought I'd put it out to you and see what you think?

Comment: Hi Carl, you can contact me by message on my [linkedIn](https://id.linkedin.com/in/rijal-tanjung-450315b4) to talk more, thanks..